# Pinging a shut down loopback interface from another system

Tags: freebsd, route, loopback

We have two device R1 and R2 running FreeBSD 9.2, on R1 we have set an ipv4 address for `lo1`:

```
R1#: sudo ifconfig lo1 192.168.80.80
```

Then add a route to R1 in R2:

```
R2#: sudo ip r add 192.168.80.80 via 192.168.12.15
```

Now we have access to R1 in R2, so ping is working. In this stage if I shut down `lo1` the ping is still works:

```
R1#: sudo ifconfig lo1 down
```

The expected behavior is that we don't have to access after `lo1` shutdown(ping don't work). FreeBSD 12.2 is also tested with the same result.

Question: Is this OK or a bug?

Comment: Is that limited to a loopback interface? Wouldn't the same happen for any other kind of interface (eg: tap0, epair0a or a spare actual interface set down)?

Comment: @A.B I tested this for actual interface and yes, same happened for them too.

Comment: The loop back address is just an alias to a physical device. Is 192.168.12.15 a physical device of R1?

Comment: @CinaedSimson, Yes

Comment: While it's a completely different routing stack, the same happens on Linux. I would tell this is related to the Weak [Host Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model). I don't know much about FreeBSD to give any answer though.

Comment: @A.B. the device is a router. I don't think strong host model is a good idea for them.  What really confused me is the shut down interface that is active and responding.

Comment: The interface isn't responding: the IP address is responding, through an other interface. That's what the weak host model is about. At least it's my idea on this case. Also about your example (not a router), OpenBSD defaults to strong host model when *not* a router. So it should hardly matter.

Comment: @A.B - I agree. Maybe it's an artifact on not having a firewall - wild guess.

Comment: @SAMPro - the LInux OS can route - so I do don't know what you mean by "it's a router".

Comment: @CinaedSimson, I mention that because I guess when device is a router it's needs to be weak host model so that it can redirect traffic that aren't belongs to it.

Comment: @SAMPro  -  routers need to be secure - hosts need to be secure, i.e., they both need firewalls.  But simply creating a firewall won't necessarily make them secure . I've never used  FreeBSD but if the security of the router weak, then the security of entire network is weak. I would argue it's the opposite - if the security of router is strong, then you might be able to get by with weaker security on the hosts. I'd recommend. Repor the problem to https://www.freebsd.org/security/ and see what they have to say about it. It may be bug - I don't know of anyother Linux OS which behaves this way.

Comment: @CinaedSimson on the contrary, *any* Linux behaves like this by default. It's even any easy way to guess if there are systems on the LAN that are configured to run libvirtd (arping 192.168.122.1), lxc (arping 10.0.3.1) etc. When the interface is down there's still a local route installed in the local routing table